# combo box field in sencha touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Combobox field

Hi guys,

I started using Sencha Touch recently and unable to find Combobox field. There seems to be some blogs on Ext.form.Combobox but the component is not available in the library or docs. The closest I got is Ext.form.Select but there is no property to allow typing text.

Was ComboBox removed in 1.1? I would appreciate some pointers.

Thanks

Comment: am using sencha touch 2.2.0 latest version ther is no support for combo box like auto completion field in sencha touch how to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are searching a component like that, isn't it? http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.0/#!/api/Ext.field.Select

Comment: No i am looking for combo box like auto completion text field like below
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox

Comment: Touch framework is customized to be used in mobile/tablet devices. So, the same functionalities of a typical combo box, is presented in this way in this framework. If you want the same look-and-feel of a combo box, I think you have to build your own component using, for example, a `textfield` and a `panel` to show the combo options when enter text in `textfield`